# Sending parameter values via intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to access the same class according to the number of user requests. I've tried following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219447/using-intent-to-send-data) that use putExtra, but it is an example for two different classes, whereas I need intent to call the same class.

here my codes:

```
   String dataX="dataX";
   int count;
   while(count >0){
       count--;
       startActivity(M_InsertData.this, M_InsertData.class);
       Intent toAlternative = new Intent(M_InsertData.this, M_InsertData.class);
       toAlternative.putExtra(dataX, count);

   }
```

Comment: Why do you want to call the same call twice? You can use onResume() method here instead of calling the activity again. Use global variable for count if that is needed.

Comment: not twice, but as many as user input. It will looping to call the same class as many as user input.

I think I should use global variable to handle the looping, but I'm confusing where should I put it.

Comment: If you want to use a global variable put its declaration right after the class declaration (before your onCreate method, assuming that is the first method defined in your class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `startActivity(M_InsertData.this, M_InsertData.class);` what you are really doing is casting those two params into an intent and calling start activity on it. Then you create an intent and add some extra data to it but never use it for anything. Instead, the last three lines in the while loop should read

```
       Intent toAlternative = new Intent(M_InsertData.this, M_InsertData.class);
       toAlternative.putExtra(dataX, count);
       startActivity(toAlternative);
```

That should properly pass the extra data (via intent) to the new activity.

Comment: Calling an activity multiple times will have too many instances in the activity stack which is not a good user experience, instead try calling the onResume() method to try to layout your activity again.

Comment: It's true that performance will suffer and it's not the most intuitive thing to do - however, he said he wanted to make as many activities as there was user input (I thought - I may have been mistaken) and as his code was almost doing that I thought it best to fix the error and not try to rewrite the logic.

Comment: I was hoping to show Jonas a way around his idea of starting multiple activities.

Comment: Thankyou for your attentions. yes, i'm newbie in java android, so maybe my code not the most intuitive thing to do. 

So now, I just want try to fix my error. hehe

i have put global variable before onCreate method(). but when I Intent the same class. The global variable back to first  initialize value. whereas i want to decrease the global variable.

how to solve it guys ??

Comment: So, your code is initializing new instances of the activity every time you iterate through the loop.  (this is the startActivity call.) Instead, you probably want to use pause/resume functionality to start the activity once and then go back to the same one on each iteration (not create a whole new instance of the activity).