# How to send data to another class?

Tags: android

I want to send my data on `textview` to `EditText` on another activity for updating of the posts and I don't know how to pass the data

```
 btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateClick.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });


    try {
        if (Cars != null) {
            tvCarModel.setText("Car Model: "+Cars.Car_Model);
            tvCarType.setText("Car Type: "+ Cars.Car_Type);
            tvCapacity.setText("Capacity: "+Cars.Capacity);
            tvFuelType.setText("Fuel Type: "+Cars.FuelType);
            tvPlateNumber.setText("Plate Number: "+Cars.PlateNumber);
            tvPoster.setText("Posted by: " + Cars.owner);

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Cars.Image, ivImage);

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in details " + e.toString());
    }
```

How can I send that using that Intent? Thanks :)

## UpdateClick

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_click);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY);
    TextView tvCarModel = new TextView(this);
    tvCarModel.setTextSize(45);
    etCarModel.setText(message);
    setContentView(etCarModel);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    galleryPhoto = new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());
    spFuelType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spFuelType);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.fuel_types,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spFuelType.setAdapter(adapter);
    spFuelType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(UpdateClick.this));

    
    etCarType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCarType);
    etCapacity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCapacity);
    etPlateNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlateNumber);
    ivImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImg);
    btnSelectPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);



    btnSelectPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(), GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Do you want to send all your data to next activity with intent ?

Comment: Only the datas on the `if (Cars != null)` sir @rushankshah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Intent to send data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219447/using-intent-to-send-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
So according to your code:

 btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateActivty.class);
            in.putExtra("id", "1");
            in.putExtra("name","abc" );
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

And on UpdateActivty :

```
Intent in1;
 in1= getIntent();

String id = in1.getStringExtra("id");
String name = in1.getStringExtra("name");
```

So on your UpdateActivty you can get id - 1 and name - abc.

Refer this  - [intent doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: So sir, `in.putExtra("?","value of the textview")` what does the 1st arguement stands for?

Comment: Yes correct. 1st Argument is your constant string. So with that 1st string you can get value in your second activity

Answer (score 0):

In your activity with the TextView, this is going to be the intent,

```
Intent yourIntent = new Intent(this, TargetActivityClass.this);
yourIntent.putExtra("CONSTANT_STRING", yourActualString);
startActivity(yourIntent);
```

In the activity with the EditText, you can get the passed data in Activity's onCreate like this,

```
String myText = getIntent().getStringExtra("CONSTANT_STRING");
```

You can just put the myText String in your EditText now.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Java serialization/deserialization](https://github.com/google/gson) library to convert java object to Json and pass Json String via intent.You can convert Json string to Java object again. Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html) and [this](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java.jsp) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing data one by one, you can create a UI model class which will store the car information and pass this entire model class to next screen